# QField map disappears when centering to GPS location?

Tags: gps, mapping, qfield

When I load a new project into QField the base map is displayed, I can digitise on and the vetor layer and it updates fine with attribute data. However the GPS position doesn't show until I click the 'canvas follows location' button, but at this point the base map diappears?

When I zoom to layer the base map reappears but the gps position disappears again!

Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you set a Scale dependent visibility which hides the basemap layer(s) when the GPS is zooming in/out?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your base map is not georeferenced.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not in the right coordinate reference system (CRS). You can check this by loading in your QGIS project an OSM/Google/Whatever basemap via the "Quick Map Services" plugin - your data will pretty sure not align to the basemap. To assign the right CRS right click your data layer-> layer CRS and select the right one (you have to do this for every layer). This will reproject your data "on the fly" - so the data in your project will be good after that. If you are going to use those layers in different projects, it might be better to export the layer and assign the right CRS while exporting!